# create single click msi file of custom installer of an application

Tags: .net, installation, windows-installer

I have an application for which I have created a custom installer. Now this installer have some supported files and exe. This also contains a folder with set of exe and supported dll's of my application.

Now if user have to install my application he can run that installer exe and can install it.

Now What I want is convert that whole thing into a single msi file, so that I can put it on my website and users can download it. So it will become like single click install stuff.

All stuff builded in .NET

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could take a look at the [Repackager from Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/convert-exe-to-msi.html). However, this requires the Enterprise edition, you cannot use it in the free version of Advanced Installer, but you do get a 30 days trial period to test it, with full features support. Also, there was recently released a [single-click install](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/release-9.2.html) support that you might be interested in.

Comment: Yes, this is possible with a VS setup project too. However, you are limited to editing the MSI dialogs, i.e. VS doesn't offer support for editing the dialogs. But for creating a simple MSI that installs a set of file it will work.

Comment: I have tried with VS. I created a setup deployment project and add my installer exe in that. So when I run that it will run my installer exe. But its not as elligent as i thought it would be. Plz suggest some best approach to do this with VS and without that also. You have requirements in front of you mentioned.

Comment: You shouldn't run the EXE from the VS package, what I would do is to extract all of its contents and create a completely new MSI package with them. i.e. the extracted files you can add in Files view, then you can configure desired launch conditions and prerequisites separately.

Answer (score 0):

What I ususally do to deploy my applications is to build an [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) setup. This is no MSI though, but in most of the cases it was absolutely sufficent for my needs.

If I need to install prerequisited like the .NET Framework, I used the bootstrapper [dotNetInstaller](http://dblock.github.com/dotnetinstaller/) which included the NSIS setup as well as the .NET Framework. It starts, installs .NET (if not present) and then executes the actual NSIS setup.

Last, I absolutely was in the need for MSI, I switched to [Wix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX) and [Wix#](http://www.csscript.net/WixSharp.html) ("Wix Sharp"). You could also create a setup project in Visual Studio .NET 2010 and let it build an MSI package for you; usually they provided too few customization options for me so I used Wix instead.

Comment: thanks for reply, I agree if i have a simple application i would create a msi for it and msi will install it and over.

But for my application i have custom installer. application can be installed from custom installer only. which itself is set of exe and dlls. Now i need to convert whole lot of things into a single msi. This is what my question is?